# What are the advantages of using bundles in iPhone development?

Tags: ios, ios4, bundle

What is the advantage of using bundle during iPhone development?

p.s. I see many SDK like Facebook SDK, Three20 are using bundles to contain images and other contents, but I am not sure why should I do so. What is the difference between using main bundle and a newly created bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple really. You use bundles just like you would use name spaces. Files in the newly created bundle could have files with the same names as files in the main bundle. Facebook SDK and Three20 have their own bundles, so that you can have any files you want in the main bundle without risking conflicts.